# Cannot start service minio: failed to initialize logging driver:error creating loki logger

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, minio, grafana-loki

I just started to explore [MinIO](https://github.com/minio/minio/tree/master/docs/docker) and I'm trying to run the following command:

```
docker run \
  -p 9000:9000 \
  -p 9001:9001 \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE" \
  -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY" \
  quay.io/minio/minio server /data --console-address ":9001"
```

but it gives me the following output:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: error creating logger: error creating loki logger: loki: option loki-url is invalid parse "https://<user_id>:<password>@logs-us-west1.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push": net/url: invalid userinfo.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default logging driver for my system is Loki.
You can either change Docker’s daemon.json file (located in /etc/docker on Linux) and put `"log-driver": "local"` or state explicitly that you want to use the local driver when you run minio image.
for docker-compose file, you can add

```
logging:
      driver: local
```

to the service `minio`